# Sharp edges after bluring part of image with cv2

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I'm using python and opencv to detect skin by HSV on this example image:

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noKnm.jpg)

```
# "org" is the original image, i convert it to HSV color and save in "frame"
frame = cv2.cvtColor(org, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# then using "cv2.inRange" to find skin part
v1_min, v2_min, v3_min = 6, 36, 89
v1_max, v2_max, v3_max = 27, 255, 255

skinmask = cv2.inRange(frame, (v1_min, v2_min, v3_min), (v1_max, v2_max, v3_max))
clothmask = 255 - skinmask

# save skin part of image in "skin" and others in "cloth"
cloth = cv2.bitwise_and(org, org, mask=clothmask)
skin = cv2.bitwise_and(org, org, mask=skinmask)

# color around the skin is black after mask apply. 
#so change it to a color near white human skin color to prevent black edges after blur
skin[skinmask == 0] = (24 * 5, 35 * 5, 220)

# now blur the skin part
skin = cv2.blur(skin, (30, 30))

# apply "skinmask" to skin part after blur
skin = cv2.bitwise_and(skin, skin, mask=skinmask)

# put the cloth and skin together
result = cv2.bitwise_or(skin, cloth)
```

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US8Kn.jpg)

I have no idea why edges around the skin is too bad. 
Any idea if the problem is from my skin selecting method or with bluring or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give me an example of the picture?

Comment: Yes. Do you think that the Skin area is being segmented?Because i couldn't find the segmented skin area only. And irregular edges is because of blurring.

Comment: @thesonyman101 the full picture is here [link](http://images.asos-media.com/inv/media/0/6/6/4/5334660/image3xxl.jpg)

Comment: @Arjun what do you mean by "couldn't find the segmented skin area only"? is there any solution for bluring without making edges like this?

Comment: @JaysOne I mean when you segment the skin color. Only the skin area should be segmented. But in this case i couldn't find.

Comment: can you post the skinmask too?

Comment: Try blurring the result as well.